# Angular - params are not appended to HttpParams

Tags: angular

I've built a custom `httpParams` function accepting a key value object as follows:

```js
private httpParamsFactory(parameters: { [key: string]: string }): { params: HttpParams } {
  const params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(parameters)) params.append(key, value)

  return { params };
}
```

I'm using the `httpParamsFactory` as following:

```js
remove = (id: string): Observable<boolean> => this.http.delete<boolean>(`some/url`, this.httpParamsFactory({ id }))
```

Despite my efforts, I was unable to include query strings in the URL, I tried debugging `httpParamsFactory`, but it turns out the query strings are not being appended, as `console.log(params.keys())` reported an empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

**Method 1**

```
private httpParamsFactory(parameters: { [key: string]: string }): { params: HttpParams } {
  let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(parameters)) {
      params = params.append(key, value)
  }

  return { params };
}
```

**Method 2**

```
private httpParamsFactory(parameters: { [key: string]: string }): { params: HttpParams } {
  const params = new HttpParams({ fromObject: parameters});

  return { params };
}
```

Reference

[Angular HttpParams](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams)

Answer (score 6):

Because you are doing:

```
params.append(key, value)
```

and you should do

```
params = params.append(key, value)
```

It's confusing since we're used to methods named `.append` to work directly on the object, but here it just returns a new object, leaving your old one untouched. I'm tripping over this too every time I'm touching this class.